# How to locate an element with the same span class?

Tags: c#, class, selenium, element, locate

In a table there are multiple elements like this:  `<span class="currency"> 0</span>`. The > 0< value is a formula value which changes each time. What would be the best way to locate the following element from the HTML:

```
<td class="alignLeft label">Initial</td>
<td class="alignRight readOnly">
<span class="currency"> 0</span>
</td>
<td></td>
```

Another element is located in this part of HTML:

```
<td class="alignLeft label">Initial</td>
<td class="alignRight readOnly">
<span class="currency"> 0</span>
</td>
<td></td>
<td class="alignRight readOnly">
<span class="currency"> 0</span>
</td>
<td></td>
```

Another one here:

```
<td class="alignLeft label">Initial</td>
<td class="alignRight readOnly">
<span class="currency"> 0</span>
</td>
<td></td>
<td class="alignRight readOnly">
<span class="currency"> 0</span>
</td>
<td></td>
<td class="alignRight readOnly">
<span class="currency"> 0</span>
</td>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried some code already?

Comment: do you want to get them all or only the first one or what exactly?

Comment: Are there multiple spans like this? Can you put IDs on them?

Comment: How do you know which one you want? Is there a label or some other text somewhere nearby? If so, please post the relevant HTML. What code have you tried and what was the result? Include error messages or why the code didn't accomplish the task.

Comment: If I had to guess, you're trying to get the value of the text of the span element, in this case `0`. If this is what you're doing, you would find the span `IWebElement`, and then you would call `GetText()` on that `IWebElement`. That's a wild guess though, please clarify your question if you can.

Comment: @mosaad, I want to get each one separately

Comment: @Gilles, yes, there are multiple spans like that. There are no ID on them and I cannot put IDs

Comment: If I use Firebug to locate an element, I get this:  **'.//*[@id='j_id0:j_id8:j_id14:j_id148:procurementTotals']/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/span'**. But this is not a perfect solution.

Comment: @ Mark Benovsky, I tried multiple variations of xpath like this **'//table[@id='j_id0:j_id8:j_id14:j_id148:procurementTotals']//td[text()='Initial']//following-sibling::td[4]//span'**. But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @RomanZadoroff the problem is that the xpath returns more than on element ?? or did I not understand the question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
// this will return a list containing all elements with the currency class
var currencyElements = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("currency"));

foreach (var element in currencyElements)
{
    // access each individual element one by one
    if (element.Text == "0")
        // do something
}
```

This will return all elements with the currency class. If you want to be more specific, ie: you only want span elements with the currency class, you will need to use the `OpenQA.Selenium.Support` package and do a `ByAll`:

```
var byAll = new OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects.ByAll(new By[] 
            { 
                By.ClassName("currency"), 
                By.TagName("span") 
            });
```

Or instead just check `element.TagName` in the first example.